# Python integers into lists

Tags: python, list, variables, integer

I am using the following code to break an integer up into bits and store in a list.

Instead of 12345, I would like it to use the contents of a variable that have already been entered previously in the code. But I can't seem to get it to work on a variable. Any suggestions?

```
digits = [] 
digits += str(12345)
```

Comment: `s = 12345` then `digits += list(str(s))` is that what you want?

Comment: `map(int, str(12345))` or `[int(digit) for digit in str(12345)]`

Comment: Are you asking for *bits*, or *digits*?  *Bits* would require a conversion to the binary equivalent.

Comment: Sorry digits, will give this a go. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (Python 2.7):

```
digits = map(int, str(12345))
```

*force evaluate `digits` with `list` if you are using Python 3.x like `digits = list(map...)`*

or list comprehensions:

```
digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(12345)]
```

or `for` loop:

```
digits = []
for digit in str(12345):
    digits.append(int(digit))
```

I assumed you want to store each digit as integers in the resulting list. Otherwise you can just take out the `int()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you wanted to split the number into ***digits***, not bits, there are a lot of very simple solutions you can choose from. Some examples:

#### Method 1: Map the digits

```
number = 12345
digits = list(map(int,str(number)))
print(digits) # prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

#### Method 2: Loop through the digits

```
number = 12345
digits = []
for digit in str(number):
     digits.append(int(digit))
```

#### Method 3: Duplicating the number, getting its remainder when divided by 10 and then divide it by 10

```
number = 12345
number2 = number
digits = []
while number2 > 0:
    digits.insert(0,int(number2) % 10)
    number2 /= 10
print(digits)
```

Comment: if you need both division and mod its probably better to just do `divmod`